# Creating navigation bar in JS

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So, this is the code that I've wrote. this works. I want the code to do the same thing but with `map()`. this function creates elements and adds the items of array

```
 function createNavbar(){
  const navList = [ 'Home', 'Buy', 'Services', 'contact'];
  let listContainer = document.createElement('nav');
  let listElement = document.createElement('ul');
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');

    // adding them to page
  document.body.appendChild(listContainer)
  listContainer.appendChild(listElement)

  let numberOfNavList = navList.length;

  for( let i = 0; i < numberOfNavList; ++i){

    listItem.textContent = navList[i];

    listElement.appendChild(listItem);

    listItem = document.createElement('li');
  } 
};

createNavbar()
```

Now, I don't know how to write it without `for`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend checking out [mcve] and describe why you have to use `map`.

Comment: So you are building the HTML as a string?

Comment: For adding new li into the ul I think you need `appendChild()` method not the `map()`. You can [learn more about appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use `map`. Using some sort of for/foreach loop is common for looping through arrays. And you will still need to loop through the results of the map function anyway. You don't use `map` to build your HTML.

Comment: I know but, this is what they want :| so this is why I need to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I understand from your question:

```js
// Assuming you have a <ul> element with the id "nav"
const navList = document.getElementById('nav');

// Your array of navigation items
const myNavigationItems = ['home', 'contact', 'services'];

// Use map() to create list items and append them to the ul element
const listItems = myNavigationItems.map(item => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = item;
  return li;
});

// Append the list items to the ul element
listItems.forEach(li => {
  navList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Navigation Bar Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul id="nav"></ul>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

const navigationItems = ['home', 'contact', 'services'];

So, basically you need to create an "UL" element in your html page, where we could insert our list of "items" (items created using JS).

In your JS file, you need:

1. get the element UL, using document.getElementById and store in a variable
2. create the array with the elements that you want to insert
3. create ths list item, thanks to map function and then append to ul element

Note: the map() function doesn't change the original array; it creates a new array with the transformed values.

```
   const listItems = "YOUR ARRAY HERE".map("EACH ELEMENT ON ARRAY" => {
  // YOUR CODE FOR EACH ELEMENT ON YOUR ARRAY
});
```

Comment: thanks, I updated my question. check it out pls